# ajax http request status returning zero on mobile browsers only

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I have been using this code for a long time successfully:

```
function doXMLReq(url, data) {
    var req = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (req.overrideMimeType) {
            req.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    }
    req.onreadystatechange = function() { doStuff(req); };
    req.open('POST', url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-length', data.length);
    req.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
    req.send(data);
}

function doStuff(req) {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        alert(req.status);
        if (req.status == 200) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    }
}
```

The URL submits a post to a PHP script which returns XML. I added in these alerts to do simple testing. Obviously where the alerts are major functionality is placed, and on every desktop browser I reach the "ok" alert after submitting my form. Additionally, if console.log(xml) type statements are issued, I can see that the XML is loaded properly on the desktop browser, and functionality is normal.

For some reason on mobile browsers (safari, android) the req.status alert always has a value of `0`, and the XML data is not returned. If I post a form directly to the URL (instead of using this JS), the browser renders the XML perfectly.

The URL is in the same directory as the original PHP file, on the same domain, etc. The header is set correctly on the PHP form which is passed through URL.

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

I am thinking that it may have something to do with `https`, since this is the only page which encounters this error, and it is also the only page in the `https` domain out of maybe a hundred pages this code is on.

I have also tried to use jQuery's `$.ajax`, because many other users in other threads have suggested that the use of jQuery could solve cross-browser woes. I re-wrote my entire PHP script and much of my javascript to accomidate for `$.ajax` and I must admit I reduced the code by a meaningful amount, but the XML HTTP request still returns `0` on mobile browsers... here is the code I used:

```
function doForm() {
    var form = $('#i_form');
    $.ajax({
            type: form.attr("method") || 'post',
            url: "fooscript.php",
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'xml', //Disables xml autoparsing
            success: function(xml){
                    doXMLback(xml);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status);
                    alert(jqXHR.statusText);
            }
    });
    return false; 
}

function doXMLback(xml) {
    var errors = $(xml).find("errors").text();
    var success = $(xml).find("uri").text();
    if (errors) {
        errmsg = errors.split("|");
        errmsg = errmsg[1];
        $('#er').text(errmsg);
        return false;
    }
    if (success) {
        window.location = success;
    }
}
```

(Obviously above instead of the form being submitted there is a div which has a simple onclick function which calls the `doForm()` function)...

How can I get mobile browsers running on 3G/4G to submit to a form and receive XML data back using ajax?

Comment: check that your mobile device's root cert store includes the signing CA of your server's SSL cert. I've encountered a fair number of SSL sites that do not have their signing CA in the mobile device's CA store.

Comment: could you please explain why having the wrong SSL cert would prevent an ajax request but not a simple POST to the same exact .php page?

Comment: browsers by default will not allow an SSL connection to go through if there's a problem with the cert. If the CA's unrecognized, the cert's expired, the issued name doesn't match the requested name, etc... all will kill an SSL connection. Since AJAX requests occur in the background, there's usually no way to pop up the usual "would you like to proceed anyways?" security warnings.